# My codeigniter models are not working because of "Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed." error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter in ubuntu. My models are not working because of  "Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed."  error occurred in my phpmyadmin.

Comment: Can you include any code related to this

Comment: post your config.php file

Comment: Please read how to ask a good question on stack

Answer (score 0):

May be, you have wrong credentials in your[ .../phpMyadmin/**config.inc.php**] file.Please check first...

You can change the username and the password in the above file with your values.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; //Change it with your values
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';  //Change it with your values
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```